# Material not textured

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm having a problem with textures not being applied to the material as you can see in the picture. It is possible to get it to work by clicking on the white X and manually selecting the image but it's too time consuming. Thanks in Advance. [image]

Comment: How did you get that already-textured scene objects? Have you tried using the options under "file > external data" about missing files?

Comment: Yes tried that already. I selected textured solid to get the textured scene

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work by selecting diffuse/color